# Passing Array of Objects to Another Class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I created a base class and an array of that class.  I am trying to pass this array to another class.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a more elegant method of accomplishing this?

```
class WaypointClass
{
private:
    float latitude, longitude;
public:
    WaypointClass(int lt, int lg)
    {
        latitude = lt;
        longitude = lg;
    }
};

class WaypointList
{
private:
    int currentWaypoint;
    WaypointClass *waypointList;

public:
    WaypointList(WaypointClass *waypoints)
    {
        waypointList = &waypoints;
        currentWaypoint = 0;
    }
};

const WaypointClass waypoints[] =
{ WaypointClass(1, 2), WaypointClass(3, 4), WaypointClass(5, 6) };

WaypointList myWaypoints(&waypoints);
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: i think it is waypointList = waypoints; and not waypointList = &waypoints; because waypointList is not an **

Comment: I am getting the following error: error: no matching function for call to 'WaypointList::WaypointList(const WaypointClass (*)[3])'

Comment: @user3813960 if you get tired with arrays and pointers, look at std::vector instead. The syntax maybe surprising at first, but it's nice to use.

Comment: Any suggestions on correct code?  I've tried adding "const" to the constructor (no luck), and removing "const" from the array I create (no luck).  I'm learning, go easy on me...

Comment: `Any suggestions on correct code?`  Correct code would have usage of `std::vector` instead of pointers.  If you did that, your `WaypointList` class would know the number of waypoints -- right now, the `WaypointList` class doesn't know anything about the actual number of waypoints.

Answer (score 4):

Not knowing what your error message is, I can immediately see a couple errors:

You declare your array as const, which means each element cannot be changed. But `WaypointList` accepts a non-const pointer, which means that it expects to be able to change each element. This is probably your compiler error.

Also, `foo[]` automatically casts to `foo*`, therefor you don't need to dereference your array with &.

Your second problem is that you pass the array over, but you don't pass the length of the array over, which means that `WaypointList` will not know how many waypoints in the array.

Comment: @user3813960 a comment is not a proper way of asking a question. no one can read your code example, and how is one supposed to answer it in a stackoverflowish manner?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you pass array as an argument, you shouldn't pass it using a reference-operator(&). This way you're passing pointer to that array, which is not what you want.
2. If the array has to be declared as const, also the argument in the function signature should be const e.x: `WaypointList(const WaypointClass *waypoints)`

Answer (score 0):

You should really use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Also you should use initializer list in your constructor instead of assign in the body, and if your member variables are `float`s, you should use that in your constructor parameter list instead of `int`.

So this:

```
WaypointClass(int lt, int lg)
{
    latitude = lt;
    longitude = lg;
}
```

Becomes this:

```
WaypointClass(float lt, float lg)
    : latitude(lt)
    , longitude(lg)
{}
```

If you use vectors, you won't need `WaypointList` class.

Here, have some reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd approach it slightly differently.  I'd use a `std::vector` to contain the waypoint list.  If you're using C++11 (and why wouldn't you?), you can define a constructor to directly accept the brace-enclosed initializer list.  A complete program show how to do this is here:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class WaypointClass
{
private:
    float latitude, longitude;
public:
    WaypointClass(float lt, float lg) : latitude(lt), longitude(lg) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const WaypointClass &wp) 
    {
        return out << "( " << wp.latitude << ", " << wp.longitude << ')';
    }
};

class WaypointList
{
private:
    std::vector<WaypointClass> m_vector;
public:
    WaypointList(std::initializer_list<const WaypointClass> w) 
        : m_vector(w.begin(), w.end()) {}
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const WaypointList &wl) {
        for (const auto &wp : wl.m_vector) 
            out << wp << '\n';
        return out;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    WaypointList myWaypoints{ WaypointClass(1, 2), WaypointClass(3, 4), 
        WaypointClass(5, 6) };
    std::cout << myWaypoints << '\n';

}
```

As expected, this prints:

```
( 1, 2)
( 3, 4)
( 5, 6)
```

Naturally, you'll need to add more to the classes to make them actually useful, but this illustrates the concepts.